# Clicking "share" button on facebook page widget throws error on iOS 9

Tags: javascript, html, ios, facebook, facebook-widgets

I'm including the official [Facebook Page Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin) (**not** my own app) on my website. The plugin shows as a widget with a "share" button at the top. On Chrome, Firefox, iOS 8.4 Safari, clicking that goes to a share page. But on iOS 9.2 Safari (on an iPhone 6), clicking that share button shows a page with the error:

> App not setup. This app is still in development mode, and you don't have access to it. Switch to a registered test user or ask an app admin for permissions.

To eliminate any other code, I made a flat HTML page that has nothing but the Facebook code and it still does this.

What could cause this?

Comment: @JonKoops It is not a duplicate. This is not my app. This is the official Facebook Page Plugin.

Comment: You will still need to register your application (Facebook page). The app id was added when you pressed the 'Get code' button.

Comment: @JonKoops How do I do that? I don't see anywhere on the page that allows that.

Comment: Something in the script, should look like this: `js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5&appId=*12345678*`

Comment: @JonKoops This indicates you don't need a facebook dev account or anything to use on the web: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs/#developer-account

Comment: Strange. Are you sure it isn't trying to open the Facebook app instead?

Comment: @JonKoops Where do I get that app id from? How do I create it? And the script Facebook gives does not have an app_id

Comment: @JonKoops It might be, but on iPhone 6/iOS9 it opens the page in a web browser.

Comment: @JonKoops The FAQ says this: "Web: If you are using Social Plugins on the web, you do not need to create a Facebook app for integrating a Social Plugin."

Comment: I see, I am being confronted with it because I am logged in.

Comment: Well, I dunno. But I'll remove the duplicate.

Comment: @JonKoops Thank you for helping me discover the answer. Their documentation is wrong. I'm guessing it's because iOS 9 tries to open it in an app which then moves into "iOS App" territory instead of the web. This is only in iOS 9 Safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason ***only*** on iOS 9 Safari (not on iOS 8, or in Android or Desktop browsers) Facebook's Page Plugin will not work without a public app id. On all other browsers/platforms, you can copy the code directly from their Social Plugins site (via "Get Code" button) and it will work.

But in iOS 9 Safari, Facebook's share button in the iframe works only if you create an App, click yes to *"Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?"* under app settings and then pass that App Id to the JavaScript source call.

This *might* happen because in iOS 9 because it attempts to open in the Facebook app instead of the browser. This crosses over into the "app environment" and thus changes Facebook's requirements despite them kicking you back to safari with an error.